# How come I see 'None' in output

Tags: python, output

Learning python from Udacity. Exercise is mentioned below. I cannot see where output 'None' is coming from. Is there something about classes that I am missing ? Thx in advance

Output is always 
0 
None

======= CODE BEGIN ==============

```
"""You can use this class to represent how classy someone
or something is.
"Classy" is interchangable with "fancy".
If you add fancy-looking items, you will increase
your "classiness".
Create a function in "Classy" that takes a string as
input and adds it to the "items" list.
Another method should calculate the "classiness"
value based on the items.
The following items have classiness points associated
with them:
"tophat" = 2
"bowtie" = 4
"monocle" = 5
Everything else has 0 points.
Use the test cases below to guide you!"""

class Classy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.classiness = 0

    def getClassiness(self):
        print(self.classiness)

    def createList(self):
        self.items.append(item)

    def addItem(self, item):

        if item=="tophat":
            self.classiness+=2
        elif item=="bowtie":
            self.classiness+=4
        elif item=="monocle":
            self.classiness+=5
        else:
            self.classiness+=0

        return self.classiness

# Test cases
me = Classy()

# Should be 0
print(me.getClassiness())
```

Comment: You didn't call the addItem() method. And you are getting None because you are printing the method call that doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

Your method getClassiness() is printing and the caller is also printing.
Maybe you meant to return a value rather than printing?

```
def getClassiness(self):
    return self.classiness
```

Answer (score 1):

class Classy(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
    self.classiness = 0

def getClassiness(self):
    return self.classiness

def createList(self):
    self.items.append(item)

def addItem(self, item):

    if item=="tophat":
        self.classiness+=2
    elif item=="bowtie":
        self.classiness+=4
    elif item=="monocle":
        self.classiness+=5
    else:
        self.classiness=0
```

## Test cases

me = Classy()

## Should be 0

print(me.getClassiness())

Comment: Hello, you are using print() inside getClassiness() method and you also return self.classiness in the last line inside your class... you should choose one between return or print